# Comparing two stored procedures with transactions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions, try-catch

I want to know if both stored procedures below could perform well to do the same thing or if there is any major difference? I have tested them and both are working, but I don't know which one I should use.

I want to select just one of the procedures, if both would perform just fine, that's alright, I want to understand what major different could arise if they are indeed different.

I also want to ensure that the transaction will be rolled back if there is an error in the procedure.

Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDeleteAnInactiveEmployee
    @TrainerID int,
    @EActive char (1)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeDetails ed 
            WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID) = 0
          RAISERROR ('Trainer details were not deleted. Trainer ID does not exist.', 16, 1)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails ed 
                   WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID AND EActive = 'Y')
            RAISERROR ('Trainer details were not deleted. Trainer is still active.', 16, 1)

        DELETE FROM [EmployeeDetails]    
        WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID AND EActive = 'N'

        COMMIT TRAN
        PRINT 'Employee ID' + CAST (@TrainerID AS VARCHAR) + ' was successfully deleted.'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK; 
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
END
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC spDeleteAnInactiveEmployee
    @TrainerID int,  
    @EActive char (1)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeDetails ed 
            WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID) = 0
          RAISERROR ('Trainer details were not deleted. Trainer ID does not exist.', 16, 1)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails ed 
                   WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID AND EActive = 'Y')
          RAISERROR ('Trainer details were not deleted. Trainer is still active.', 16, 1)

        DELETE FROM [EmployeeDetails]    
        WHERE TrainerID = @TrainerID AND EActive = 'N'

        COMMIT TRAN
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Employee ID' + CAST (@TrainerID AS VARCHAR) + ' was successfully deleted.'
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
        PRINT 'An error has occurred and the transaction was not committed' 

        SELECT
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Detail on the side: why are you using `IF EXISTS()` to check one condition, and then also  `SELECT COUNT(*)....... = 0` for the other condition? The `IF EXISTS` is **definitely** the preferred way to go (and performs better, too!) - typically, you only need to know *if* at least one entry exists - you couldn't care less about *just how many* there really are...

Comment: STOP printing! STOP counting to determine if rows exist. Why do you need a transaction for a single DML statement? And don't change an error into a resultset (2nd version) - the caller will not have any error / exception to catch to know that an error occurred.

Comment: There is no functional difference between them. The error handling is slightly different one throws an error on an error, the other selects error details. Which you prefer is up to you. `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;` is an imporovement over `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: And be consistent. Use statement terminators everywhere - eventually they will be required.

Comment: Regarding error handling, the first CATCH block is the way to go.

Comment: I'm not using - `IF Exists ... = 0`  They are two different statements. The first `IF ...=0` is checking that the the TrainerID does not exist, the second `IF Exist ...` is checking that the condition is true, so that I'm not deleting active members.

Comment: `IF EXISTS( .... )` is equivalent to `IF( SELECT COUNT(*) ..... ) = 0` and as @marc_s pointed out `IF EXISTS` is faster.